# Can't run Python scripts on an Apache web server (Windows 7)

Tags: python, apache

Here's the Python script itself (test.py):

```
#!/Users/misha/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32
print("Content-Type: text/html\n")
print("\n\n")
print("<h1>Test</h1>")
```

I have this in my Apache's configuration file httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs">
    ...
    ...
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    ...
    ...
</Directory>

AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
```

I restart Apache--everything else works just fine, but when I try to point to my Python test file in my browser, the server throws an **Internal Server Error** at me.

Here's my Apache's latest log file entries (I have edited them a little bit just for readability's sake):

```
(localhost-error.log)
[Thu Feb 11 14:24:39.357362 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 16872:tid 1028]
(OS 5)Access is denied.  : [client 127.0.0.1:54957] AH01223:
couldn't spawn child process: C:/Apache24/htdocs/test.py

(localhost-access.log)
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Feb/2016:14:24:39 -0800] "GET /test.py HTTP/1.1"
500 528
```

I don't even know what to do now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that Apache can't find the python interpreter. You should make sure the shebang in your file is correct. Test if you can run the file from a different folder.

Comment: The shebang line was the problem. Changed it to: #!/Users/misha/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/python.exe (I just added "python.exe" on the end) Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put shebang line in your code.

And check your script permissions. It should be executable.

To change file permission to executable in Linux: chmod +x filename.py

I don't know about windows.